# Unable to access few objects in S3

Tags: amazon-s3

Why some objects are accessible in S3 bucket and some are not. Following are the below errors we faced. Though I checked the access and it seems to be fine. Exception while connecting S3: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadBucket operation: Forbidden botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied

Comment: you need to check if you have any policies applied to your bucket, you could specify policy by prefix in a s3 bucket.